# Project Euler 18 - C++ Passing Array By Reference

Tags: c++, arrays

See: http://projecteuler.net/problem=18 for a better explanation of the problem than I could give here.

I like my algorithm; It's not brute-force.  I look at all of the 3x3 triangles at the bottom of the pyramid to calculate which route is best, then assign that value back to the row.  That's why my function is called ConsolidateBottomThreeRows -- I'll end up calculating the best path from the bottom up, assigning to the top-most of the bottom 3 rows each time, creating a smaller and smaller pyramid until my top row contains the answer.

My issue isn't a question of algorithm, simply syntax.  I can't figure out [yes, even with Googling] how to get my arrays passed correctly.  Here is my output when I try to compile:

```
C:\MyApps\Euler>g++ Prob_18.cpp -o Prob_18
Prob_18.cpp: In function 'void ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(int*, int*, int*)':
Prob_18.cpp:17:20: error: request for member 'size' in 'top', which is of non-class type 'int*'
```

And my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int CrunchSmallTriangle(int top[], int middle[], int bottom[])
{
    int biggest=0;
    if(middle[0]+bottom[0] > biggest) biggest=middle[0]+bottom[0];
    if(middle[0]+bottom[1] > biggest) biggest=middle[0]+bottom[1];
    if(middle[1]+bottom[0] > biggest) biggest=middle[1]+bottom[0];
    if(middle[1]+bottom[1] > biggest) biggest=middle[1]+bottom[1];
    return biggest+top[0];
}

void ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(int top[], int middle[], int bottom[])
{
    int SmallTop[0], SmallMiddle[2], SmallBottom[3];
    for(int x=0;x<top.size();x++)
    {
        SmallTop[0]=top[x];
        SmallMiddle[0]=middle[x];
        SmallMiddle[1]=middle[x+1];
        SmallBottom[0]=bottom[x];
        SmallBottom[1]=bottom[x+1];
        SmallBottom[2]=bottom[x+2];
        top[x]=CrunchSmallTriangle(SmallTop, SmallMiddle, SmallBottom);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int row1[1]={75};
    int row2[2]={95,64};
    int row3[3]={17,47,82};
    int row4[4]={18,35,87,10};
    int row5[5]={20,4,82,47,65};
    int row6[6]={19,1,23,75,3,34};
    int row7[7]={88,2,77,73,7,63,67};
    int row8[8]={99,65,4,28,6,16,70,92};
    int row9[9]={41,41,26,56,83,40,80,70,33};
    int row10[10]={41,48,72,33,47,32,37,16,94,29};
    int row11[11]={53,71,44,65,25,43,91,52,97,51,14};
    int row12[12]={70,11,33,28,77,73,17,78,39,68,17,57};
    int row13[13]={91,71,52,38,17,14,91,43,58,50,27,29,48};
    int row14[14]={63,66,4,68,89,53,67,30,73,16,69,87,40,31};
    int row15[15]={4,62,98,27,23,9,70,98,73,93,38,53,60,4,23};

    ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(row13, row14, row15);
    ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(row11, row12, row13);
    ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(row9, row10, row11);
    ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(row7, row8, row9);
    ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(row5, row6, row7);
    ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(row3, row4, row5);
    ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(row1, row2, row3);

    cout<<row1[0];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: By reference is typically `int (&arr)[SIZE]`. Look up the spiral rule to read it out from the declaration. The other stuff you're trying to do needs some kind of a container like `std::vector`, though, which can be a reference like a normal variable can to boot.

Comment: My advice would be to create a proper Triangle class that can handle input/output, and easy access to its elements like `triangle(i, j)` for accessing the jth column of the ith row. Your current hard-coded representation is not very flexible.  Once you have proper data structures in place, formulating the generic algorithm will be much easier (as opposed to "hand-unrolling" your loop as you currently do). Ref: https://bitbucket.org/mitchnull/project-euler/src/634d2f8a50cb/src/triangle.hpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I agree with the other answers that switching from raw C-arrays to `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>` would be the best move. However, that being said, as chris commented, because your C-arrays are statically sized, making `ConsolidateBottomThreeRows` into a function template makes the following possible as well:

```
template<std::size_t TopN, std::size_t MidN, std::size_t BotN>
void ConsolidateBottomThreeRows(int (&top)[TopN],
                                int (&middle)[MidN],
                                int (&bottom)[BotN])
{
    int SmallTop[1], SmallMiddle[2], SmallBottom[3];
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x != TopN; ++x)
    {
        SmallTop[0] = top[x];
        SmallMiddle[0] = middle[x];
        SmallMiddle[1] = middle[x + 1];
        SmallBottom[0] = bottom[x];
        SmallBottom[1] = bottom[x + 1];
        SmallBottom[2] = bottom[x + 2];
        top[x] = CrunchSmallTriangle(SmallTop, SmallMiddle, SmallBottom);
    }
}
```

Note that your declaration of `SmallTop` has the wrong dimensions.

Comment: Oh snap, SmallTop DOES have the wrong dimensions!  lol  Thanks

Comment: I have to run, so I will come back to this thread tomorrow -- However, I'm really interested in implementing what you've done here, FYI.  Thanks for taking the time to do that.

Comment: Eh, I suck at this whole struct stuff.  I went ahead and used a vector, and it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: @armani : I'm not sure what you mean by 'struct stuff'. The code here is a drop-in replacement for your `ConsolidateBottomThreeRows` function, no other code needs to change.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays do not have a `size()` method!  You will either need to pass the size to the function as a separate parameter, or use a container (such as `std::vector`).

Comment: Better yet, use std::array or boost::array

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `top.size()` with a size passed in to the function. Better yet, don't use arrays and use vectors instead. Then your `top.size()` will work.